# Running a command w/ quotes in parameters works with commands.getoutput() but not subprocess module

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm creating a python program that calls a number of other programs and scripts (on Unix(SUNos) + Linux). I'm using subprocess everywhere except for 1 script.

The script for which I don't use subprocess is a perl-script which has been made into an executable. Somehow it does not let me use subprocess on, but it works with the (deprecated) commands package.
I would like to understand why it does not work with subprocess (in other words: what am I doing wrong ;-) )

(What the actual perl command is not important, but it returns the full name and email of a user as result)

What I tried:

```
PERL_CMD = [ '<executable perl-script>', '-rt', '"users"', '-eq', '"name"' '"<user_name>", '-fs', '":"', '-fld', '"fullname"', '"email"' ]
full_name, email = subprocess.check_output( PERL_CMD ).split(':')
```

But this does not work.

Where the commands variant does work:

```
PERL_CMD = '<executable perl-script> -rt "users" -eq "name" "<user_name>" -fs ":" -fld "full_name" "email"'
full_name, email = commands.getoutput( PERL_CMD ).split(':')
```

Has anybody an idea why I can't get subprocess to work?

It is annoying me that I can get it to work for everything except this (eventhough I have an acceptable (but deprecated) workaround).

Comment: What does "But this does not work."  work mean? Do you get an exception? If yes, which one?

Comment: @Mike: It is a long time ago that I ran the subprocess version, so I don't know the exact exception anymore, but it gave an exception.
The answer given by Charles Duffy below explains to me why it goes wrong, so I now know the cause. 
Thanx anyway for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using syntactic quotes in the `commands.getoutput()` case, and literal quotes in the `subprocess.check_output()` case. Without `shell=True` (which you shouldn't use), there's no shell to parse quotes as syntax, so there's no such thing as a syntactic quote, other than the quotes that are syntax *to Python itself*.

So, just take out the `"`s that you injected into your arguments:

```
# this contains quotes that are syntactic to Python only, and no literal quotes
perl_cmd = [
  '<executable perl-script>',
  '-rt', 'users',
  '-eq', 'name', '<user_name>',
  '-fs', ':',
  '-fld', 'fullname', 'email' ]
```

---

To explain a bit more detail --

When you pass `"name"` to a shell as part of a command, the quotes are *consumed by the shell itself* during its parsing process, not passed to the command as an argument. Thus, when you run `sh -c 'echo "hello"'`, this passes the **exact same argument** to `echo` as `sh -c 'echo hello'`; the `echo` command can't even tell the difference between the two invocations!

When you pass `'"hello"'` as an argument to `subprocess.Popen()`, by contrast, the outer quotes are consumed by Python, and the inner quotes are *passed as literal to the inner command*. That makes it equivalent to `sh -c 'echo "\"hello\""'` (which likewise passes literal quotes through to `echo`), not `sh -c 'echo "hello"'` (which does not).